# Error message when using lrm() and validate() from the rms package

Tags: r

I am trying to use `validate()` from the `rms` package but get an error. More specifically, I fit an ordinal logistic model using `lrm()` and then assess my results with `validate()`.

Please find some code below:

```
library(data.table)
library(rms)

DT2 <- data.table(internal_model_rating_number = c(5,5,5,5,6,6,5,5,5,5),
                  ratio = c(2.0665194,1.2264998,1.0333628,0.6936382,-0.1883890,
                        -0.2349949,-0.5062086,-0.5204016,-0.4401635,-0.5824366))
lrm.model <- lrm(internal_model_rating_number ~ ratio, 
                 x = T,
                 y = T,
                 data = DT,
                 maxit = 1000)
validate(lrm.model, group=internal_model_rating_number, B=200, bw=T)
```

Note that the `group` argument when running the code for my actual data (not displayed) is necessary, because some categories of the target variable occur very rarely.

The piece of `validate()` code returns the error:

```
Error in predab.resample(fit, method = method, fit = lrmfit, measure = discrim,  : 
  object 'internal_model_rating_number' not found
```

Do you know how I can solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the data has to be specified before the grouping variable.

Try this `validate(lrm.model, group = DT2$internal_model_rating_number, B=200, bw=T)`

You also had a small typo (try `data = DT2` instead of `DT`.)

If you don't want to specify the data again, you can use `attach(DT2)` and then run your model.

```
library(data.table)
library(rms)

DT2 <- data.table(internal_model_rating_number = c(5,5,5,5,6,6,5,5,5,5),
                  ratio = c(2.0665194,1.2264998,1.0333628,0.6936382,-0.1883890,
                            -0.2349949,-0.5062086,-0.5204016,-0.4401635,-0.5824366))

attach(DT2)

lrm.model <- lrm(internal_model_rating_number ~ ratio, 
                 x = T,
                 y = T,
                 data = DT2,
                 maxit = 1000)

validate(lrm.model, group = internal_model_rating_number, B=200, bw=T)
```

Once you're done, if you'd like to detach the data, use `detach(DT2)`

Comment: Thank you very much @Type Writer, that solves the error.